# Is it possible to make an Android phone share a file automatically using Tasker/Macrodroid/Automate or similar software?

Tags: tasker, shareit, macrodroid

Is it possible to make an Android phone share a file automatically using Tasker/Macrodroid/Automate or similar software?

Hello,

I have a file which I want to share automaticallly and regularly to another app.

So it's a text file and I want to share it to a specific app on regular intervals.

Is there a way to make Tasker/Macrodroid/Automate or similar software accomplish this?

i have tried but not found a way to do it yet.

Know a solution to this one?

Vesa

Samsung Galaxy S5

Comment: Not possible with Macrodroid

Comment: Which app is it that you want data to be shared with? Please link it too.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, It is possible using Tasker.

The action **File >> Share File** states:

> Share File
>
> Share a file with another **application** or **device**.
>
> If Mime Type is not specified, Tasker will attempt to deduce it.
>
> If Show Chooser is specified, Android will display a selection of
>   possible ways of sharing the file, in a dialog.
>
> If not specified, the chooser may be shown anyway if there is no known default way of handling that Mime Type.
>   Some Android versions may ignore Chooser Title.

Trigering the task gives the possible options of sharing the file. If I understand correctly what you are trying to achieve, I have added screenshots:

[image] [image] [image]

---

**Update**

If your Tasker version doesn't have the **File → Share**  share action, you can use the [AutoShare plugin](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joaomgcd.autoshare):

It lets you use the regular Android share menu and choose AutoShare from the list and the Subject, Text or files will be sent to Tasker where you can do what you want with them.

The developer (Joao) has also made [various resources](http://forum.joaoapps.com/index.php?resources/categories/autoshare.28/) available to get you quickly going. And more [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/tasker/comments/1t84nb/take_a_screenshot_then_share_it_to_another_app/)

Comment: There is no share file option after choosing file in Tasker as far as I can see.

Comment: But I cannot create a share file task because there is no share file task option as far as I can tell in my Tasker app.

Comment: Screenshot: http://imgur.com/a/aBrOW

Comment: No. As far as I an tell I have the latest version of tasker, at least there is no update option for Tasker in the Google Play store. Which Tasker version do you have? My version is 4.3u4m.

Comment: I use version 4.9u3m

Comment: @Vesa I think I have found an alternative solution to achieve your goal

Comment: How? Please describe.

Comment: I have put everything in the answer, read the last updated section, I included relevant resources, let me know if it works. Looking forward to your feedback